# Filter Resource Availability using URL parameter

Tags: project-server, ms-project-server-2010

I am using project server2010.

I have list of Resource Name and their GUID in hand. I want to display each Resourcename as a link in my webpage.

When we click on a resourcename , it will take you to resource availability page. There I want to display datas for the particular resource.

Is there any way to pass the resource name or GUID as query parameter and display resource availability for that particular GUID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the parameter name is "ResourceUIDS" .

if we pass resavailability.aspx?ResourceUIDS={GUID} it wil show only the particular user's res availability